# What if __enter__ and __exit__ raises?

Tags: python, contextmanager

I'm working on a simple package to control my power supply remotely. I wrapped the logic in a class, let's call it `PowerSupply`. The communication is over a serial port. Also before actual control a specific command should be transferred in order to switch the device to the remote mode. There is also command to revert it back to the local mode. So here is the description of the context manager I would like to use:

- Setup

  1. Open serial port
  2. Switch the device to the remote control mode
- Teardown

  1. Turn off the voltage
  2. Switch the device to the local control mode
  3. Close serial port

The problem is (almost) each of the above points can raise actually. Here is *very* simplified code :

```py
class PowerSupply :
    def __init__(self, port: str) :
        self._device = serial.Serial(port)

    def __enter__(self) :
        try :
            self.setMode(EMode.REMOTE)
        except Exception as outer :
            try :
                self.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()) # should be cleaned anyway
            except Exception as inner :
                pass
            finally :
                raise outer # we don't want to miss this error
        else :
            return self

    def __exit__(self, _, __, ___) :
        try :
            self.setOut(Out.OFF)
            self.setMode(EMode.LOCAL)
        except Exception as e :
            raise e # we don't want to miss this error
        finally :
            self.close()

    def setMode(...) :
        pass # can raise

    def setOut(...) :
        pass # can raise
```

The usage is straightforward:

```py
with PowerSupply("/dev/ttyUSB0") as ps :
    ps.setMaxVoltage(5000);
    ps.setMaxCurrent(1000);
    ps.setVoltage(1000);
    ps.setOut(EOut.ON);
    # work
```

I see one problem (excluding the code full of `try`s) with this approach: *`__exit__` replaces the exception from the `with` body*. Actually, it is not quite a problem in my case because I made every single command to be logged and any error is also logged internally. But anyway, could be a problem in other projects.

What is a recommended approach to deal with such kind of cases when both setup *and* teardown raise?

Comment: `What is a recommended approach` do nothing, just let the exception propagate. `to deal with such kind` How do you _want_ to "deal" with such case? It's up to you, there is nothing to do. Two notes, you can do plain `raise` to re-raise an exception and you can do `raise MyException("something") from e` to add a `__cause__` attribute to the exception.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you're recommending to remove `try/catch` from the `__enter__`. But the resource might have been allocated already and propagating the exception contradicts the idiom. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, I understand the question is quite general and subjective. Maybe I'm asking more about "if this approach acceptable or it has some design flaws" ?

Comment: Side note: `raise e` is a bad practice, since that messes with the exception stack trace. If you wan to propagate the exception, use a bare `raise` or don't catch it at all

Answer (score 0):

Python does preserve the TB info of all chained exceptions, there is mostly no need to do anything, but to ensure you run your tear-down code in the `finally` clauses. Just as @KamilCuk puts in the comment above.
Previous exceptions are chained by setting the `__context__` attribute in the last raised exception - the default traceback print handles that nicely.

If at any point you know that one exception *caused* the other downstream, during handling, you may use the  `raise ... from ...` syntax - that changes the message to your user to "this exception was the direct cause of this next exception" instead of the default "during handling of this previous exception this following exception was raised". (The context in this case is preserved in the Exception's `__cause__` attribute instead)

What might be nice is to factor-out the `__exit__` method to simplify the understanding of your flows.

```
class PowerSupply :
    def __init__(self, port: str) :
        self._device = serial.Serial(port)

    def __enter__(self) :
        try :
            self.setMode(EMode.REMOTE)
        except Exception as outer :
            #try :
                self._inner_exit() 
            #except Exception as inner : # redundant block - Python will add the "outer" exception as a context for "inner"
                #raise inner 
            #finally : # redundant  - just let the exception buble up
                #raise outer # we don't want to miss this error
        else :
            return self
        
    def _inner_exit(self):
        try :
            self.setOut(Out.OFF)
            self.setMode(EMode.LOCAL)
        #except Exception as e :  # redundant block: any exception will propagate
        #    raise e # we don't want to miss this error
        finally :
            self.close()
        

    def __exit__(self, exctype, exc, tb) :
        #try :
            aelf._inner_exit()
        #except Exception as e : # redundant block: "exc" is added as context for the inner "e" exception
            #raise e from exc  # attach  expertise/tooling to follow).
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer: I'll take a look at it later. For now you can edit the question a bit (regarding the second code snippet). :)